# React + TS, Undefined component type, while components are in same namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactjs

Sup.
My stack is React.js + TypeScript.
I have two classes in same namespace.
In two separate files (MaterialSelector.tsx and MaterialSearchResult.tsx)

MaterialSelector.tsx :

```
namespace Materials {
 export class MaterialsSelector extends React.Component<Props, State>{public render(): JSX.Element {
      return <div className={'aeworms-materials-selector' + (this.state.searching ? ' -searching' : '')}>
        <div className='-search-form'>
         <input
           type='search'
           placeholder='Naam, artikelnummer, …'
           value={this.state.query}
           onChange={ev => this.search((ev.target as HTMLInputElement).value)}
           onFocus={ev => this.startSearch()}
           onBlur={ev => this.stopSearch((ev.target as HTMLInputElement).value)}
         />
         {this.state.searching
           ? <button type='button' className='-cancel'>Annuleer</button>
           : null}
         </div>
         <table className='-search-results'>
          <tbody>
           {this.state.searchResults.map(material => {
             <MaterialsSearchResult />
            })}
           </tbody>
          </table>
       </div>
    }}
```

MaterialsSearchResult.tsx :

```
namespace Aeworms.Materials {
export class MaterialsSearchResult extends React.Component<Props, State> {


    public render(): JSX.Element {
      return <tr>
              <td></td>
             </tr>
    }

}}
```

I got this warning:

*Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `MaterialsSelector`.
warning @ react.js:19287*

Which is point to .
Somehow the MaterialSelector class don't "see" the MaterialsSearchResult class, even if it is in same namespace. 
I've tried to import this class, (import MaterialsSearchResult = Materials.MaterialsSearchResult) still got the same error.
Tried export as default, leads to another error:

*Cannot find name 'MaterialsSearchResult'*

So, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you import `MaterialsSearchResult` in `MaterialSelector.tsx`?

Comment: import MaterialsSearchResult = Materials.MaterialsSearchResult;